# How to dynamically create ActionLink in MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am able to redirect the user with code in a function like this:

```
 window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ShippingSummary", "Shipping", new { id = 2 })"
```

I have the id in a variable but I need to assign it to the ActionLink dynamically. Something like this

```
var ID = 2;
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ShippingSummary", "Shipping", new { id = ID })"
```

I get an error that ID is not defined. I have tried to create the actionlink as a string first but that didn't work. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, you are mixing Javascript and C#. The Javascript will be executed in the browser, but the C# will be executed on the server, so you can't mix them like this.

Instead, you should do:

```
var ID = 2;
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ShippingSummary", "Shipping")" + "?id=" + ID;
```

In this instance, Razor will emit the first part of the Controller Action route, and then you can add the needed query string parameter to the path.